# Regex matching in online tester but not in JAVA

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I'm trying to extract the text `BetClic` from this string `popup_siteinfo(this, '/click/betclic', '373', 'BetClic', '60€');`

I wrote a simple regex that works on [Regex Tester](http://www.regextester.com/index2.html) but that doesn't work on Java.

Here's the regex

```
'\d+', '(.*?)'
```

here's Java output

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found
at java.util.regex.Matcher.group(Matcher.java:485)
at javaapplication1.JavaApplication1.main(JavaApplication1.java:74)
Java Result: 1
```

and here's my code

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("'\\d+', '(.*?)'");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(onMouseOver);                
System.out.print(matcher.group(1));
```

where the `onMouseOver` string is `popup_siteinfo(this, '/click/betclic', '373', 'BetClic', '60€');`

I'm not an expert with regex, but I'm quite sure that mine isn't wrong at all!

Suggestions?

Comment: Good answer below, but also the question mark seems redundant.  .* should match 0 or more characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call `find()` *before* `group(...)`:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("'\\d+', '(.*?)'");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(onMouseOver);                
if(matcher.find()) {
  System.out.print(matcher.group(1));
}
else {
  System.out.print("no match");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `group(1)` without having first called a matching operation (such as `find()`).- which is the cause of `IllegalStateException`.

And if you have to use that grouped cases for replacement then this isn't needed if you're just using **$1** since the `replaceAll()` is the matching operation.